# IBM Cognos Connection Aggregates Within Header

Tags: aggregation, cognos

I am creating a Daily Labor Report within IBM Cognos Connection, hosted through UltiPro software.  I have all fields and groupings laid out exactly how I want them, only I want there to be totals to show within the header of each grouping.  For example, I want to show the total hours worked within each Shift grouping and each Department grouping.  Within the data table, I added in a summary row with aggregates for all the necessary columns (Scheduled Hours, Regular Hours, Overtime Hours, etc), but it only shows at the very bottom of the report that aggregates up the entire day's numbers across all departments and shifts.  Any ideas as to how to accomplish showing the aggregates within each grouping?

Comment: By grouping, do you mean the report is "sectioned"? If so this is likely a case for a second query linked via a master-detail relationship. If not, could you post some sort of visual representation of what you're describing?

Comment: Users without many points cannot post images.

Comment: I would gladly add an image to better explain the situation, but I do not have enough user points to be allowed to post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand everything, try this:

```
Delete your current summary.
Add footers to each of your groupings.
Click the Summarize button.  That should place summaries in each of your footers.
Unlock the report (the little padlock icon on the toolbar).
Drag your summaries from the footers to the corresponding headers.
```

Comment: I tried working on Andrew's comments.  I have added in the footers for each grouping level and clicked Summarize, but all aggregations within that icon are grayed out and not available.  The only time I am allowed to summarize anything is when I highlight all rows within a column.  Then the summarize feature works, but it puts the totals within the footer of the table, not of the grouping footers.

Comment: Sorry, left out a step.  Select the column(s) you want to summarize, then click the button.

Comment: That works Andrew! I am now able to get the aggregate totals at the top within each Shift and Department level.  Do you know how to create spacing and/or alignment so they are separated and look better as well?  Currently there is zero spacing between the totals and I had to change the background colors of each just to distinguish where one number ended and another began.

Comment: Select the header. Under `Structure > Headers & Footers`, select `Split List Row Cell`.  That should make it match the columns in the list.